# Python cut sentence by length

Tags: python, string, delimiter, cut

I have a big sentence and a length. How do I cut my sentence so that it doesn't exceed my length and put the rest of the sentence on a new line with a space as delimiter. This for example can't exceed my length of 15:

```
This sentence is way too long.
```

So I have to become:

```
This sentence
is way too
long.
```

Comment: what should happen if a single word is longer than 15 chars?

Comment: See the [`textwrap` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) in the standard library.

Answer (score 8):

The standard library has the `textwrap` module for jobs like this.

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> print('\n'.join(textwrap.wrap("This sentence is way too long.", 15)))
This sentence
is way too
long.
```